# Why am I getting an infinite loop when I use Scanner.hasNext() in a while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, file-io, java.util.scanner

I am new to Java. I am trying to iterate through a file and write each string into an ArrayList. To do this I have code that looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException
{
    File customerData = new File("accountData.txt");
    Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(customerData);
    ArrayList<String> stringArrList = new ArrayList<String>();

    String currentWord = "";
    System.out.println("About to enter while loop");    

    while(fileReader.hasNext());
    {
        currentWord = fileReader.next();
        stringArrList.add(currentWord);
    }
    System.out.println("We have exited the while loop");
}
```

However, this code gets stuck in an infinite loop for some reason. Even if I put a print statment as the first line in the while block it doesn't execute.

The accountData.txt file is arranged like so:

```
String String String String String
String String String String String
...
```

I've read all over and read that often times this is problem because people aren't using Scanner.next() to move the pointer but I believe that I am doing that. I have no idea what is going wrong.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

> this is problem because people aren't using Scanner.next() to move the pointer but I believe that I am doing that

You would be using `Scanner.next()`, except the `;` terminates the loop body. Remove it. Change

```
while(fileReader.hasNext());
{
    currentWord = fileReader.next();
    stringArrList.add(currentWord);
}
```

to

```
while(fileReader.hasNext()) // <-- no semicolon
{
    currentWord = fileReader.next();
    stringArrList.add(currentWord);
}
```

Comment: Please just vote to close as typo or select one of the hundreds of duplicates.